# Microsoft Access Form combo boxes and calculations

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox, calculation

I have a question regarding a data entry form for project pricing estimates I am currently building.

To give you some context: The form will be used to enter data and complete calculations. It will replace an excel spreadsheet comprising of 59 columns, 1-15 rows (it varies by requirements) per project estimate. Average number of projects is 50-60 per year saved in respective customer folders. If there is an update to the estimate, a new version of the spreadsheet is created and saved in the respective customer folder. Hence, in certain scenarios, there are can be up to 10 versions saved per customer per project.

I am seeking to create a form-table combination for each of the customers: hence 10-15 forms with the same structure. Currently, I am only creating one form and table combination as a test. The table designed to replace the spreadsheet will use a total of 30 auto number foreign keys to store information. To be user friendly, I am using combo boxes in my form, where the user types in text but is stored as a foreign key in the table.

On top of this, I need to include calculations. For example, if the user selects certain options from my combo boxes, this will result in a calculated answer in an adjoining form field. Part of the calculated answer will use data in a linked table from another access database. Based on the options selected in the form combo boxes, the database will scan specific columns in the linked table to find matching entries to the selected combo box options. If a match exists, a price is extracted from that linked table. So say the combo box options selected are origin Miami and destination Salt Lake City, the database will scan for those 2 entries in the linked table. If that entry combination is found in the linked table, this price is to be used in the calculation. This price will then be multiplied by two other components entered by the user in the form, resulting in the calculated answer.

My questions:

1. Regarding the calculation example I gave above, can the above scenario be realistically accomplished in Microsoft Access? If so I am assuming I have to use VBA and/or Macros to do so?

a. If so, is it suitable to use my data entry form to complete it? Or is there an alternate way to achieve this result?

2. Will 30 combo boxes combined with such calculations have a significant impact on the speed of my form and database, especially as more data is added to the form and given that 10-15 forms will use the same structure? I have thus far included half of the combo boxes in 1 form, completed 1 test entry and I find that occasionally there is a slight lag when opening the form.

a. If it will impact my form's performance, what are my options/other form controls I can use to minimize lag and maximize speed?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You wouldn't use 15 forms. Access is not a spreadsheet. The answers are 1: Yes, 2: Maybe. But your question is OT at SO which is all about code. You should address this at, say, UtterAccess or Experts Exchange.

Comment: I would like to use 15 forms because I would like to store each of the customer projects (which have many versions) in a seperate table. Thanks I will post there.

Comment: But that is not how to use a database. Use one table, one form, and filter on the customer to study. Before you initiate anything, search for and read up on "How to normalise a database".

Comment: Yes I know this breaks normalisation. I am thinking of doing this to satisfy the users needs. They will need to access the data they inputted in the form and they will prefer to have forms for each of the customers especially since there can be many versions within a project for a given customer. It's hard to follow the strict database principles while satisfying user requirements.

Comment: True, but they can't tell or sense, if they watch a full table or a filtered table. And there is a simple technique to open one form multiple times with different filtering. Multiple tables is a dead end that will only cause you endless and increasing troubles.

Comment: Thanks Gustav; I am working on this project on my own and can't ask for advise to anyone in my team. Really appreciate it :)